# Constructing file paths for each row of a datatable in C#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-datatable

I need to iterate through a DataTable and columns in each rows and do some data manipulation.

Below given is an extract from my code, I use c#.net. I expect maximum rows in datatable will be less than 25K.

How I can improve the code for better performance?

```
DataTable metadaDataTable = GetMetaDataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in metadaDataTable.Rows)
{
    string newfileName = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataColumn col in metadaDataTable.Columns)
    {
       if (col.ColumnName != "path_variable")
       {
           newfileName += row[col].ToString() + "_";
       }
     }
       newPath = CleanFileName(newfileName);
   }
```

Comment: You need to give us waaay more context, e.g. what's the purpose of this code, how many rows, what's the DB structure, etc. Why are you using ADO.NET and not Entity Framework?

Comment: This is an addition in the erxisting code, so I need to use something which fix in the same class. Maximum rows can be less than 25,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple trick here would be to take the column processing outside of the row processing (the column metadata should not change while the rows probably will):

```
using (var metadaDataTable = GetMetaDataTable())
{
    var columns = metadaDataTable.Columns
        .Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Where(col => col.ColumnName != "path_variable")
        .ToList();
    var path_variable = metadaDataTable.Columns
        .Cast<DataColumn>()
        .SingleOrDefault(col => col.ColumnName == "path_variable");
    string path_variable_value;

    foreach (var row in metadaDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
    {
        var newfileName = columns.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, col) => current + (row[col] + "_"));

        newPath = CleanFileName(newfileName);
        path_variable_value = path_variable == null ? null : row[path_variable].ToString();
        // TODO: do something with the path_variable_value before continuing the loop.
    }
}
```

Note also I've sprinkled a liberal amount of LINQ in there to signify intent rather than mechanism.

Finally, Also surrounded the lifetime of `metaDataTable` with a `using` construct as `DataTable` implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: Can I include the "path_variable" also in the columns? After getting "newfileName" I need to get the value of "path_variable".

Comment: @blue added some quick stuff.

Comment: How do I exclude any columns with null or empty value in this statement - "var newfileName = columns.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, col) => current + (row[col] + "_")); "

Comment: I believe that's starting to exceed the scope of this site and you may want to ask such additional question(s) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

string is immutable
`newfileName += row[col].ToString() + "_";` is inefficient

```
DataTable metadaDataTable = GetMetaDataTable();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in metadaDataTable.Rows)
{
    sb.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn col in metadaDataTable.Columns)
    {
       if (col.ColumnName != "path_variable")
       {
           sb.Append(row[col].ToString() + "_");
       }
    }
    newPath = CleanFileName(sb.ToString());
}
```

if you want to get serious

```
DataTable metadaDataTable = GetMetaDataTable();
int colCount = metadaDataTable.Columns.Count;
int skip = 0;
foreach (DataColumn col in metadaDataTable.Columns)
{
   if (col.ColumnName == "path_variable")
       break;
   skip++;
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in metadaDataTable.Rows)
{
    sb.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
    {
       if (i == skip)
           continue;
       sb.Append(row[i].ToString() + "_");
    }
    newPath = CleanFileName(sb.ToString());
}
```